# How do I load an image after I generated a .jar file with eclipse?

Tags: java, image, swing, jar, embedded-resource

I just wrote a mini-program in java that takes an image and prints it on frame.
I used JPanel to load the image:

```
public class Board extends JPanel {

    private Image mummy;

    public Board() {

        initBoard();

    }

    private void initBoard() {
    
        loadImage();
    
        int w = mummy.getWidth(this);
        int h =  mummy.getHeight(this);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));        
    }

    private void loadImage() {
    
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("mummy.png");
        mummy = ii.getImage();        
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(mummy, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

and JFrame to print it.
Then I created the .jar file via the export section of Eclipse (Runnable JAR file).

The problem is that now I can't load the image when I run the .jar file. I tried putting the image everywhere on the .jar zip but simply the code doesn't load it.

Everyone knows how to load the images using this method, or should I use a wrapper to create the .jar file instead of eclipse?

Comment: In some cases, the jar doesn't contain all resources, or maybe the resource has a different path from "mummy.png". Can you look inside your jar to see if exist your image?

Comment: You need to use `Class.getResource` to load a resource from a jar

Comment: Following up on Greg's suggestion from above check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Loading Images Using getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource). This approach will work in all situations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Guys I figured it out:

The ImageIcon(""), has as default starting directory where all the code is put, but varies between an eclipse project and an eclipse generated Runnable jar file.
-When it's a project: it's the directory of the project, so where the src and bin directory are.
-When it's a .jar: src doesn't exist, and the starting directory now is the directory where the .jar file is situated.

For example:
for simplicity let's situate the created runnable files in the ~ directory.

-Using `new ImageIcon("src/images/mummy.png")`, you'll have to put the directory "images" with the relative files in the src directory of the project, where the source files and packages are, making a structure like this:

...eclipse-workspace/Project/src/cli/*.java    -where the source code is.

...eclipse-workspace/Project/src/images/mummy.png   -where the file is.

After you created the runnable .jar with eclipse, you'll have to put a new "src" directory with the "images" in the same directory where the .jar is, making a structure like this:

~/project.jar               (the .jar file)

~/src/images/mummy.png      (the image I loaded in the code with `new ImageIcon("src/images/mummy.png")`

Thanks for the comments anyways.

Comment: *Thanks for the comments anyways.* - the comments are the proper way to load the images. The tutorial has a complete section on how to do this. The point of using the getResource() method is that is will find the resource anywhere on your classpath..

Comment: camickr, the point of my question was not how to load an image, or to find another way. My question was "I did this, where should I put my images?". I then found out and it was actually pretty obvious... btw, how do I close a question page?

Comment: *My question was "I did this* - just because you did something one way does not make it the proper solution. Of course there are many ways to solve programming problems. However there is usually a preferred standard approach the will result in fewer problems in the future resulting in less need to ask questions when something doesn't work the way your expect. You were given the approach recommended by the Swing developers.

Comment: camickr, I don't think you understand what I said. I'll repeat myself, again. I didn't ask for the proper way to write code to do what I did there, I asked what was happening in that code when it wasn't in a project anymore, as it wasn't perfectly clear. As a similitude, I didn't want to know that in an ALU 2+2 = 4, but what happened in the ALU when I passed in 2, 2 and the sum operation. I'm studying code, I can't do that if I don't know even how the loadImage method works in a .jar generated by eclipse. Is it clear now?